# flutter text button issue

Tags: flutter, dart

When I input TextButton inside either in Row or any Widget it's show error

> The method 'TextButton' isn't defined for the type '_LoginScreenState'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'TextButton'.dartundefined_method
> such this :

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('don \'t registered ? '),
            TextButton(child: Text('Register'),
          ],
        ) //Row
```

Did flutter update it to another widget?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the function onPressed. See below

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('don \'t registered ? '),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Register'),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **TextButton** Widget you forgot the required property for **onPressed** function please add it, refer my answer below hope it's helpful to you.
Refer official documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html) for **TextButton**

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children:[
            Text('don \'t registered ? '),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Register'),
              onPressed: () {
                    print ('Button pressed');// when you pressed on button console gives you the message test it
                   // Call your onPressed function here
                 },
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You were just missing a closing rounded bracket after "TextButton(child: Text('Register'),"

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children:[
            Text('don \'t registered ? '),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Register'),
              onPressed: () {
                    print ('Button pressed');// when you pressed on button console gives you the message test it
                   // Call your onPressed function here
                 },
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Just add a rounded bracket after it and you're done